# invalid index when installing Ardour after build

Tags: software-installation, compiling, ardour

I have successfully compiled Ardour 6 from source, which I conclude because it runs and operates correctly when run up from its build directory as follows:

```
./ardev
```

However when I try to install it, I get the following error:

```
sudo ./waf install
Waf: The wscript in '/home/colic/ardour' is unreadable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/colic/ardour/.waf3-2.0.19-1216edef773cb93a573c0abd4d9bece5/waflib/Scripting.py", line 102, in waf_entry_point
    set_main_module(wscript)
  File "/home/colic/ardour/.waf3-2.0.19-1216edef773cb93a573c0abd4d9bece5/waflib/Scripting.py", line 142, in set_main_module
    Context.g_module=Context.load_module(file_path)
  File "/home/colic/ardour/.waf3-2.0.19-1216edef773cb93a573c0abd4d9bece5/waflib/Context.py", line 362, in load_module
    exec(compile(code,path,'exec'),module.__dict__)
  File "/home/colic/ardour/wscript", line 203, in <module>
    other = parts[1].split('-', 1)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

To me this implies some error in the installation script, a python error on an attempt to access an array element that is out of bounds

But why that would be in an established install script I dont know.

Does anyone know what this error means, or even better how I fix it.

Comment: Are you building from a source tarball, or from git? If the latter, which version exactly? What does `git describe` return?

Comment: Im building from git, version 6.9 (git checkout 6.9), confirmed by git_describe.

Comment: Anyone else out there have any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I can see, `wscript` just does a process call to `git describe HEAD`, then splits the result twice, first on the . character  `parts = rev.split ('.', 1)` then again on hyphen `other = parts[1].split('-', 1)`. It's hard to see how this can give a `list index out of range` error unless the result of `git describe` doesn't contain at least one `.`

Comment: ... the only corner case I can think of is that something in how `sudo ./waf install` runs that prevents python's `subprocess` from executing `git describe` at all, so that `rev` is an empty string - perhaps a permission or ownership issue (which might relate to the message "The wscript in '/home/colic/ardour' is unreadable")